# Alamofire, SwiftyJSON update UI after receiving response

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

Hi I'm writing code to talk to server api using Alamofire and then parse the JSON respond using swiftyJSON. After get all the result, I want to update to UI accordingly but seem cannot

here is my Alamofire request with swiftyJSON parsing (in Pokemon.class)

```
func downloadPokemonDetails1(completed: DownloadComplete) {

    let url = NSURL(string: _pokemonUrl)!

        Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { response in

//            print(response.description)
            guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                print(response.result.error.debugDescription)
                return
            }

            let json = JSON(response.result.value!)
//            print(json.description)

            self._name = json["name"].string
            self._height = json["height"].string
//            print(self._height)
            self._type = json["types",0,"name"].string
   //            print(self._type)
}
```

My DownloadComplete in constanst.swift

```
typealias DownloadComplete = () -> ()
```

Note: I can print all the value (valid) so response is ok

But the problem is that when I call the function in a ViewController. the UI is not updated

Here is how I call the function in viewController

```
pokemon.downloadPokemonDetails1 {
            print(self.pokemon.type)
            self.updateUI()
        }
```

updateUI() func:

```
 func updateUI() {
        nameLbl.text = pokemon.name
        typeLbl.text = pokemon.type
        heightLbl.text = pokemon.height
  }
```

Is anyway to update UI after receive the data from server? anyhelp is much appreciate. Thanks

Comment: did you use the `main thread` to execute your `updateUI()` method?

Comment: hi, how to check whether main thread execture updateUI()? I put in under viewDidLoad() func

Comment: you just explicitly run the method by enclosing it in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){}`. See https://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1 for more info. Updating UI always requires `main thread` by the way.

Comment: Hi event enclose UI is not update also. There is some thing wrong with my call func. I try to print on viewController but nothing happen. Can only print inside fuc (pokemon.class)

Comment: hi just figureout. I need to call completed() to at the end of alamofire request